# Importing Excel Data to datatable with format currency

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am importing data from an excel file to a vb datatable with one column having a 'currency' format. However, upon retrieval, I noticed that the currency sign is no longer included in the datatable. How to include the currency sign? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe that's not even the problem. It's almost always appropriate to store data in its true form. Having the currency stored as a number is correct. The currency sign is only applicable when displaying it. Depending on how the currency is displayed in your application (your question is *so* vague), there are different ways to format the data for display. You would need to provide some code. Also, is this vb.net or vba? They are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the format of the data grids cell.

Something such as this might work:

```
DataGridView.Columns("CurrencyColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
```

And I believe if you want to set it to a desired amount as decimal places, you can do as such

```
DataGridView.Columns("CurrencyColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
```

The above should set it to 2 decimal places, which I believe can be switched with other numbers as well